# Clarification on creating on cmdlets in powershell

Tags: c#, .net, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-cmdlet

I am new to powershell and I am trying to create a cmdlet which will be accessed through powershell modules, Cmdlets is mainly to access another class file from the assembly need to pass the value through the cmdlets and get the output back from it.Can anyone correct me if I am trying something wrong in the way I implement?

Code which I Tried:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Management.Automation;
#region GetProcCommand
namespace Sample.Powershell
{
    [Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "type")]
    public class GetProcCommand : Cmdlet
    {
        #region Parameters
        private string inputType;
        [Parameter(
               Position = 0,
               ValueFromPipeline = true,
               ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty]
        public string Name
        {
            get { return this.inputType; }
            set { this.inputType = value; }
        }
        #endregion Parameters

        #region Cmdlet Overrides

        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {

            if (this.inputType == null)
            {
              //  WriteObject(Process.GetProcesses(), true);
            }
            else
            {
                ExampleClass _ec= new ExampleClass();
                _ec.sample(inputType);


            } 
        } 

#endregion Overrides
    } 
#endregion GetProcCommand
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to create a powershell module which has a cmdlet which access another class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33933658/is-it-possible-to-create-a-powershell-module-which-has-a-cmdlet-which-access-ano)

Comment: Please do not re-post a question when it has been closed. Improve (edit) the question you already posted to get it re-opened.